# Image with multiple layers

Tags: java, image

In our gamedesign we wish to implement collisiondetection by (hopefully) being able to check the backgroundlayer of our mapimages. We are currently using .png but the problem is that the transparency channel (alpha) is useful information for the top layer (deciding transparency), we cannot use this layer as a bitmask without making the image transparent. Since our game is a tilebased RPG the checks would be simple (iterate every blocksize pixel, if alpha=1 then this block is a map-solid and cannot be  walked through or stepped upon).

The alternatives (the ones we can think of) require too much setup. For instance having a second image leaves no room for error as they have to match completely. Also designating individual blocks in the image as walkable requires us to store this information in either the image or manually set this, which is too brute-force. The transparency layer idea (if you can suggest a way to make it work) is ideal as you can just shadow the image in photoshop and create a transparent image, requiring almost no work.

TLDR; Can you use the alpha channel of png in java as a form of bitmask without rendering the transparency? Any imageformats easily handled by swing that can store multiple layers?

Answer (score 0):

you're operating on a single value, so why not reserve 1 number in 1 of the other channels. Keep your 16 million colors, but reserve b=0 as your collision color. People won't be able to tell the difference between 0,0,0 and 0,0,1 so just never use pure black, problem solved without weird transparency encoding.

Comment: What if the mapimage actually has a nearly black pixel with (0,0,1). There is also the problem of encoding this.

Comment: it's your game, you control the game assets. You check for that stuff, there's plenty of tools for that. Using a full extra channel if all you need is a necessary 1 bit value, adding a full channel is very wasteful. You could, of course, use the alpha channel and set it to 255 or 254 depending on whether you need collision, but that's really silly. You just needlessly increased the asset size by 1/3rd.